# Zend Framework, Form - Form renders with just one field

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, frameworks, zend-form

I am using ZF Form to generate forms.
I wrote a class

```
class Form_Client extends Zend_Form 
{ 
    public function init() 
    { 
        $this->setMethod('post');

        $name = $this->createElement('text', 'email',array('label'=>'Name','size'=>'50')); 
        $name->setErrorMessages(array('Field is required'));
        $name->setRequired(TRUE);       
        $this->addElement($name);

        $contact_person = $this->createElement('text', 'email',array('label'=>'Contact person','size'=>'50')); 
        $contact_person->setErrorMessages(array('Field is required'));      
        $contact_person->setRequired(TRUE);                 
        $this->addElement($contact_person);

        // add element: submit button
        $submit = $this->createElement('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Save'));
        //$submit->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper')); 
        $this->addElement($submit); 

        $btn = $this->createElement('button', 'cancel', array('label' => 'Cancel'));
        $btn->setAttribs(array('onClick'=>'window.location="/system/login"','style'=>''));
        //$btn->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper')); 
        $this->addElement($btn); 
    }
}
```

In my controller I've got

```
public function editAction()
{
    $frmClient = new Form_Client();
    $frmClient->setAction('edit');

    /*submit*/
    if ($this->_request->isPost()) { 
            if ($frmClient->isValid($_POST)) { 
                $data = $frmClient->getValues();
            }
    }

    $this->view->form = $frmClient;
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer('form');
}
```

And in my View there's

```
<?php echo $this->form; ?>
```

The problem is that form renders with just the first input fields.
Do you know what's wrong with that?

Thanks,
Jacob

Answer (score 2):

Both of your text fields are called "email" - Each field must have a unique name.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, both form elements have the same name. Try something like:

```
[..]
$name = $this->createElement('text', 'name',array('label'=>'Name','size'=>'50'));
[..]
$contact_person = $this->createElement('text', 'contact_person',array('label'=>'Contact person','size'=>'50'));
[..]
```